# Binding Errors on collapsed Gui Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a lot of bindings in a grid which are collapsed or visible based on the selecteditem in a treeview tree. so based on the object, the correct view pops up and the other collapses.

But I get lots of binding errors of the gui elements in the collapsed views. that is so, because I have a "myselecteditem" in the view model that fits to the view which is opened, but not to the collapsed ones.

is my approach stupid? can i suppress bindings for gui elemnts in a collapsed grid?

Code (shorted for lazy readers):

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="G_G_Content" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid x:Name="G_G_Abrechnung_Control" Visibility="Collapsed">
        [...]
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="G_G_Mitglied_Aktion" Visibility="Collapsed">
        [...]
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="G_G_Mitglied_Aktion_Nachweis" Visibility="Visible">
        [...]
    </Grid>
</Grid>

        <TreeView
            x:Name="G_tv_explorer"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItemSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedItemChanged="G_tv_explorer_SelectedItemChanged"
            TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />
```

**C#:**

```
private void G_tv_explorer_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
        //set active treeviewitem
        if (G_tv_explorer.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //set treeview && ViMo
            ViMo.TreeViewSelectedItem = e.NewValue;
            RedrawGui();
            ViMo.MySelectedItem = ((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Tag;
        }
}

public void RedrawGui()
{
    //redraw gui, dependant on selectedtreeviewitem
    if (ViMo.TreeViewSelectedItem != null)
    {
        if(ViMo.TreeViewSelectedItem is string)
            MessageBox.Show("Dummy");
        else
        {
//this is a placeholder
            if (((TreeViewItem)ViMo.TreeViewSelectedItem).Header.ToString() == "Verwaltung")
            {
                G_G_Mitglied_Aktion_Nachweis.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                G_G_Abrechnung_Control.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else if (((TreeViewItem)ViMo.TreeViewSelectedItem).Tag is MVVM.Model.Jahresabschluss)
            {
                G_G_Mitglied_Aktion_Nachweis.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                G_G_Abrechnung.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Where RedrawGUI only sets the Grids Visible / collapsed based on the Object Type of the SelectedItem

Comment: _is my approach stupid?_ That depends on so many things. But is it MVVM ? Certainly not.

Comment: _can i suppress bindings for gui elemnts in a collapsed grid?_ You don't really have to. It doesn't matter if UI elements are hidden or collapsed, if you try to bind to something which doesn't exist, you will get binding errors!